# Render a different component evenly in flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this article list, which is a FlatList (on my current working project). So, in this app, I use Admob. I want to display a banner ad every 2 times on my FlatList. I have included an image of my expectations,

[image]

For more simplicity, I have a text component,

```
<Text>Banner Ad Here</Text>
```

I'm expecting to render this **Text Component** after every 2 items in my `FlastList` below,

```
<FlatList
   data={DATA}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
/>
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me. Thanks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use index for that.
Meaning whenever the **index** is even add your **header**.

**Example code:**

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <View>
      {index % 2 === 0 && index != 0 && <Text>Banner code</Text>}
      {/* your  JSX */}
      <View>
        <Text>Normal JSX</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```